# Right work script after in e-shop cart after reload number of amount

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this script:

```
$('#header').addClass('domaci-hlava');
$(".box-account-links span:contains('Přihlášení')").addClass("prihlaseni-pryc");
$(".box-account-links a:contains('Registrace')").addClass("registrace-pryc");
$( ".prihlaseni-modal" ).load( "https://www.profikotouce.cz/login/ #login-form" );
```

This script is on this webpage https://www.profikotouce.cz/. When I'm in cart https://www.profikotouce.cz/kosik/ and change number of amount of the product, elements in header (login) doesnt work.

Can anybody propose right solution? Thank you so much.

Maybe can help, when script will be running only in header, right?

Comment: When I change the product quantity on the shopping cart page, it redirects me to a login form. Do you want a different behavior to occur?

Comment: Hi, when i change number of products its taking me to login. Is the same thing you looking or may be i did not understand your question